# input button with font Awesome

Tags: forms, input, icons

So, I have this button inside a form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
```

and I want it to display ths fontawesome's icon, which works like any other icon feature in css.

```
<i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i>
```

but I've tried a few ways and none worked! Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only the input must be changed to  as:

```
<button type="submit">
   <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i>
</button>
```

but also the css should match:

```
form button {
padding-top:10px;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
font-size:30px;
float:right;
color:#333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a button instead of an input?

```
<button type="submit">
    <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> 
    Entrar
</button>
```